# Could the Romanian gând/gândi (thought/think) be ultimately of Latin and/or Albanian origin?

Tags: etymology, romance-languages, language-contact

*A [gândi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/g%C3%A2ndi)* is in modern Romanian the common/main form of the verb "to think", based on the noun *gând* ("thought"). It is considered of Hungarian origin, from "gond".

I don't want to bluntly dismiss the Hungarian ultimate origin. But the word in Hungarian is signaled of unknown origin, which for any etymologist is not an answer and begs for further investigation — something which I have tried to do below. - To farther illustrate my logic: Hungarian word `furulya` (flute) is surely of [Romanian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/furulya#Etymology) origin. Why sure? Because it is present in [Albanian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flojere#Albanian). But its origin is [disputed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fluier#Etymology), either Latin or of Balkan substrate. That's what I was imagining for `gând` too.

It is common, even obligatory, for the etymology of Romanian words that don't have a clear Latin or Slavic root, to look *next* at the [Albanian-Romanian linguistic connection](https://(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albanian%E2%80%93Romanian_linguistic_relationship)). In this case, where a word has a Hungarian connection, but one that involves ultimately an unknown origin, it is only normal to check that Balkan relation too, whether on a Latin etymological branch or not.

— "[Gând](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/g%C3%A2nd)" has taken precedence over the blatantly Latin *a cugeta* (to think, cogitate), *cuget* (mind, faculty of thought), now more of literary/poetic or archaic use, so that *cugetare* means "cogitation" as "aphorism", "apothegm". Somewhat frequent still are *cugetat/necugetat* (wise/foolish).—

*gând*= thought, intention, preoccupation, representation, mental state

- *gândire* = noun: theory, thought (as in ”*gândirea marxistă*”=Marxist
  thought)
- *gânditor* = adjective: thoughtful, noun: thinker
- *pe negândite* = adverb: without thinking, improvised, without
  letting/having time to think
- *pe gânduri*, as in *a sta/cădea pe
  gânduri*=to ”be, stay/fall” on thoughts=to be/become thoughtful,
  anxious
- *a (se) îngândura* = to become reflexive, anxious
- *îngândurat* = adjective: reflexive, anxious, thoughtful, preoccupied,
  ”full of thoughts”
- *îngândurare* = anxiety, concern

There is no officially accepted complete etymological dictionary of Romanian for the moment, only personal works, but there seems to be a consensus that the Romanian “thought”/*gând* is [of Hungarian origin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/g%C3%A2nd#Etymology) ,from *gond*.

*[gond](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gond#Hungarian)* = "trouble", "preoccupation", (rare, archaic) "care" — leading to:

- *gondos* (*os*=with) – careful
- *gondtalan* (*talan*=less) – careless
- *gondatlan* (*atlan*=without) – carefree
- *gondoz* (*-oz* – verb-forming suffix) – to take care, tend
- *gondnok* (-*nok* – noun-forming suffix) – caretaker, guardian

but especially:

- [*gondol*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gondol): to think, consider, believe, guess – exactly the sense of the Romanian *gând*

— So that, the Cartesian *cogito ergo sum* is translated with the same root in Romanian (“*gând*esc, deci exist”) and Hungarian ([“*gond*olkodom, tehát vagyok”](https://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogito_ergo_sum))!

In both languages the verb is based on the noun. In Hungarian it is said to be of unknown origin, in Romanian it is said of Hungarian origin.

But there is clearly a common root. If the root is not Hungarian (Hun. *gond* > Rom. *gând*), then it must be Romanian (*gând > gond*), apparently still with an unknown origin, which for Romanian usually leads to the search for a substrate, Balkan (possibly Thracian-Dacian) origin, and/or an Albanian origin.

What strikes me in the case of Romanian words of clear Hungarian origin is that the Hungarian root-form is much more productive  (e.g. Romanian *[fel](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fel#Etymology_11)*) or the Hungarian word is itself based on Hungarian elements that are absent in Romanian —like Romanian *[oraș](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ora%C8%99)*, ”city” < Hun. *város*=vár, “castle” +‎ *-os*, derivative noun-forming suffix, [*alcătui*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alc%C4%83tui) ”to put together”, [*cheltui*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cheltui), ”to spend” etc.

*Gond* is not like that.

---

As for possible Albanian relations of *gând*, there seem to be *some* traces:

In Albanian there is:

- [*gënjej*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/g%C3%ABnjej) = to lie, to deceive – from Vulgar Latin *ingannō*, from Latin *ganniō*. Compare Romanian *[îngâna](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AEng%C3%A2na#Romanian)* (to mimic, mock, deceive, hum or murmur in order to mimic, to mockingly imitate)
  hence:
- [*gënjeshtër*](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto%26tl&tl=en&text=g%C3%ABnjesht%C3%ABr&op=translate) – noun: deceit, lie
- *[gënjeshtar](https://m.dict.cc/albanian-english/g%C3%ABnjeshtar.html)* = liar
- [*zhgënjej*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zhg%C3%ABnjej) = to disappoint, disenchant, disillusion

Romanian form for “(to) lie” is *(a) [minți](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/min%C8%9Bi#Etymology)*, noun: *[minciună](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/minciun%C4%83#Etymology)*, *mincinos/mincinoasă* (liar, masc./fem.) with equivalents in all Romance (Ital. *mentire*, Fr. *mentir* etc), from Latin *mentior < mens, mentis*, which in Albanian has given *mend/[mendje](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mendje)*= "mind, thought, think" and   [mendoj](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mendoj) = “to think” (hence *[mendoj, pra jam](https://glosbe.com/en/sq/I%20think%20therefore%20I%20am)* = “I think, therefore I am”). -  [That](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mentior#Latin) is related to or descending from Proto-Italic *mentjōr*, denominal verb from *mens,mentis* (“mind”). ***The meaning "to lie" stems from a semantic shift*** "to be inventive, have second thoughts" > "to lie, conjure up".

Romanian follows this common Romance semantic shift  (think>lie - *mens/mentis* > *mentior*) while Albanian doesn’t, and the elements of that shift (“think” and “lie”) end up different in the two languages. Thus,

English             *think*     and     *lie*   are:

- In Romanian:      *gând(i)*   and     *minți*
- In Albanian:      *mend(oj)* and  *gënjej*

Some shift seems to have taken place here, so that there is a cross-correspondence between Romanian “lie” and Albanian “think”, and between Romanian “think” and Albanian “lie”. The first is no surprise, the two forms  (*minți* and *mendoj*) have the same Latin root (*mens/mentis*), the different meanings being the result of the common  Romance semantic shift that Romanian has followed while Albanian has avoided. But what about the second correspondence? That could be a shear coincidence, where it not for the fact that the two elements (*gândi* and *gënjej*) are paralleled by the other two.

[image]

What are the chances that the Romanian *gând(i)* is a result of a semantic shift from the Albanian term?

(In that case, it would mean that Hungarian ”to think” is ultimately of Latin origin: *gond* < Rom. *gând* < Alb. *gënjej* <  Vulg. Lat. *ingannō* < Lat. *ganniō*!)

Comment: Where are you seeing that inverse shift in Albanian? *Gënjej* only means 'to deceive' (a meaning it already had in Vulgar Latin, judging by the other Romance reflexes), not 'to think', and *mendoj* 'to think' never shifted to 'lie' in the first place.

Comment: @Cairnarvon - I'll edit. You're right, "symmetrical shift" is wrong. I'll delete this for now.

Comment: @Cairnarvon - I have tried to fix it: the idea is that Romanian words for *thought* and *lie* may be semantically and morphologically (hence possibly etymologically) paralleled in Albanian in a (double) semantic shift.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that the oldest meaning of the *gond* cluster of words in Hungarian is 'care' and only secondarily 'think', and that this secondary meaning happens to be the one that made it into Romanian. If the borrowing went from Romanian to Hungarian it's hard to explain how that primary meaning was completely lost in Romanian, even before considering the plausibility of a semantic shift 'deceive' → 'care' and the formal difficulties like the origin of the *-d-*. It's also not obvious to me why Albanian is involved in this discussion at all.

Comment: @Cairnarvon - The basic meaning of both `gond` and `gând` is "concern", not "care" as in "taking care", but what *weighs* on the mind, cf.  Latin pēnsāre from which `peser/penser` (Fr.) etc. English "thought" also has that double connotation (dialectal, also in "thoughtful" etc). But that very fact that in both Hungarian and Romanian that structural double meaning is present pleads strongly against the Latin origin from *inganno*. - [Romanian-Albanian connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albanian–Romanian_linguistic_relationship) is always useful to consider in problematic etymologies .

Comment: @Cairnarvon - I have posted here not as much because I dismiss the Hungarian connection but because I wanted opinions on an alternative hypothesis that I have tried to properly articulate. And in that I think I've done ok: I don't think my question is bad and  down-vote worthy.

Comment: @Cairnarvon - To farther illustrate my logic: Hungarian word `furulya` (flute) is surely of [Romanian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/furulya#Etymology) origin. Why sure? Because it is present in [Albanian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flojere#Albanian). But its root is [disputed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fluier#Etymology), either Latin or of Balkan substrate. That's what I was imagining for `gând` too.